# Why is my Laptop unable to ping my server but my phone is?

Tags: ping

My Laptop and my phone are both connected with the same Wireless lan.
My Server is connected to a switch which is connected with my router.

There is a web-interface running on my server. When I start my Laptop I can access it fine, but after about 5min I lose the connection.

My phone is still able to ping the server, so the server is still running.

When I try to ping the server from my laptop it says that the destination host is unreachable. Same when I try to ping my phone or any other device in my network, except for the gateway.

My Laptop runs Linux Mint

Comment: Is it possible that you have more than one DHCP server in your local network?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possibilities - the one which I think most likely is at play here is that the WiFI card in your laptop is not very good/has buggy drivers.  (Is it a realtek card perhaps?)

It is also possible that your laptop and phone are using different ping protocols - there is more then 1 way of doing ping.  (ICMP is very common, but UDP can be used to ping things as well.  It is sometimes possible to use tcp as well, but thats unlikely here)